# router/bridge is eating bandwidth

Tags: wireless-networking

hi a few days ago i put a router/bridge on my basement to increase the range of wifi but suddenly theres a few times that my ping spike alot when im playing online games like google ping is 20 then suddenly spiked to 500-700(i have a cmd opened with google ping) for no reason and the thing is theres no other device or laptop connected to the router/bridge during that time(im the only one using the internet), though i can return my ping back to normal whenever i remove the router wire on the main modem, what seems to be the problem and how do i fix it? anyway my router/bridge is linksys e2500, thanks.

Comment: ive set the router as bridge.

Comment: Just noticed that you're talking about WiFi so I now really hjave _no_ idea what is connected how and which times you compare.

Comment: hmmm its like this, before i add the router/bridge on my basement i dont have any ping spike problem with my connection this happened only after i add the router/bridge thats my problem, though removing the router will prolly solve my ping issues but i kinda need extra range on my wifi in the basement.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, it is obvious the problem is the bridge, but you failed to provide any additional information beyond that. Try [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing wireless bridging/repeating. This has the effect of increasing the range but halving (or worse) the throughput. When you have problems this exacerbates the issue. A weak link makes for many retransmissions and thus causes a delay.

You should undo the change and purchase Homeplugs, they will give you the range without disrupting the existing network.